# Politeness perspective and meaning in context

Tags: english-to-german, meaning-in-context

From the politeness perspective and meaning in context, is the following German statement

> Würden Sie bereit sein, mit mir ein Gespräch über das Thema zu haben?

the same with the English statement:

> Would you be willing to have a conversation with me about this topic?

Comment: May I note here that "ein Gespräch zu haben" is not very good style. Yes, it is understandable, but the better accepted form is "ein Gespräch führen". I would suppose that this is a translation issue from English where "to have a chat or a talk" would be a standard expression.

Comment: The context seems a bit absent after the title? Is this a business setting, private conversation,…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence should be changed slightly:

> Wären Sie bereit, mit mir ein Gespräch über dieses Thema zu führen?

However, this would be better in my opinion:

> Wären Sie bereit, sich mit mir über dieses Thema zu unterhalten?

Other possibilities:

> Haben Sie Lust, ...
>
> Hätten Sie Interesse daran, ...
>
> Was halten Sie davon, ...
>
> Wie wäre es, wenn wir uns über dieses Thema unterhielten?
>
> Hätten Sie etwas dagegen, wenn ...
>
> ...

All these sentences sound polite and fit to the meaning. Nevertheless, a little more context would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In this context we say »mit jemandem ein Gespräch **führen**« instead of »**haben**«.

But the most simple and common translations contain »[be]sprechen« instead of »ein Gespräch führen« which usually is too formal for spoken German.

> - Wären Sie bereit, mit mir über dieses Thema zu sprechen?
> - Würden Sie mit mir über dieses Thema sprechen?
> - Könnten wir dieses Thema [vielleicht] miteinander besprechen?
> - Dieses Thema hätte ich gern mit Ihnen besprochen, wenn es Ihnen nichts ausmacht.